# Update post terms

Tags: php, wordpress

The function `wp_set_post_terms()` works fantastically however I'm looking to add some terms to a post at a later date. I've tried using `wp_set_post_terms()` and `wp_set_object_terms()` but they just overwrite what's already there. I thought `wp_add_object_terms()` was the answer to my question but it has the same functionality whereby overwriting the original terms.

Any way to append terms via code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

However, [`wp_set_object_terms();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms) seems made for your case:

From WordPress Codex:

> Relates an object (post, link etc) to a term and taxonomy type (tag,
>   category, etc). Creates the term and taxonomy relationship if it
>   doesn't already exist.

```
<?php wp_set_object_terms( $object_id, $terms, $taxonomy, $append ); ?>
```

**The clue**

`$append` parameter is *bool*: if true, **tags will be appended to the object**. If false, **tags will replace existing tags**

Hope it helps!

Comment: Totally missed the `$append` param. Couldn't figure out why it was overwriting. Sorted, thanks!

Answer (score -3):

```
wp_set_object_terms($id, (int)$parent, "warehouse");
```

Comment: You've totally missed the point of the question. That function works but overwrites the terms already set.